Frobenius theorem on real division algebras with involution
Let $W$ be a real irreducible representation (irrep) of a finite group $G$. $D:=End_G(W)$ is a division algebra by Schur's lemma, and, by Frobenius theorem on real associative division algebras, $D$ is isomorphic to either the reals $\mathbb{R}$, complexes $\mathbb{C}$, or quaternions $\mathbb{H}$. Let's call this isomorphism $\varphi$.
Suppose $W$ is endowed with an $G$-invariant inner product (i.e. $\langle g\cdot u, g\cdot v \rangle=\langle u , v \rangle$ for all $u,v \in W$ and $g \in G$). So, $W$ is an orthogonal irrep, and $D$ has the involution that acts as the adjoint corresponding to the $G$-invariant inner product. We know that $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, and $\mathbb{H}$ all have involution. Furthermore, they are normed division algebras. However, my question is how to prove that $\varphi$ preserves involution. Is this even true?
Added:
I consider involution to be trivial map in $\mathbb{R}$, complex conjugate in $\mathbb{C}$, and the standard involution in $\mathbb{H}$ $\left((a+ib+jc+dk)^*=a-ib-jc-dk\right).$ We even do not need to define involution in $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, and $\mathbb{H}$ because there is a unique positive involution up to isomorphism in real central division algebras. The involution must be positive when we want to correspond involution to adjoint. For the definition of positive involution see follows:
Let $*$ be a $K$-linear involution in $K$-algebra $A$, where $K$ is a field with unique ordering. $*$ is positive if the map $A \to K$ via $a \mapsto tr(a^*a)$ is positive definite with respect to the ordering in $K$. Here, $tr(a)$ means the trace of $a: x \mapsto ax$.

What is the involution on $\mathbb R$?  Even in the other cases it might help (you) if you precisely describe the involution.

Thx for your consideration. Please check the added part in my question.

Crossposted to MO: https://mathoverflow.net/q/478875/6518

No, that post is more general than this question. I still don't know how to show, that there is a *-algebra isomorphism between $End_G(W)$ and $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$, or $\mathbb{H}$, when $W$ is orthogonal irrep.
